# Cache handling in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

Is folder
/.cache/google-chrome
safe to delete ?

would it affect the surfing experience on chrome?

Answer (score 2):

It will just delete the cache and nothing else. You can continue to use `google-chrome` as before.

You can go a step further and install applications like BleachBit. `sudo apt-get install bleachbit` Recently my disk was full and hence I need a clean up. You can select the folders you feel need to be cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't affect the surfing experience. It just removes the caches.